# The menu (Navigation bar) becomes collapse unstylish for a few second. need Solution

Tags: css, wordpress, preloader

I am facing a problem after deactivating the pre-loader. When someone tries to open the website all the menu (Navigation bar) becomes collapse unstylish for a few seconds. After a while when the page has fully loaded the menu gets its style.

I think the CSS file is loading after the website is gets fully loaded, maybe this is the reason. How Can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please share debugging details. Where can we see the issue ?

Comment: show some screens or code to help us resolve this in some way

Comment: @HariomBalhara
https://gamanicoreafoundation.com/ 
please check this site. all the menu (Navigation bar) becomes collapse unstylish for a few seconds. After a while when the page has fully loaded the menu gets its style.

Comment: @Dev Please check the link

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not only link us to your webpage. You should also post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here in the question, because it will be hard for us dig through the website to find the problem. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the css inside head tag before any scripts etc,
add preload to your css and critical js files

Comment: https://gamanicoreafoundation.com/ please check this site. all the menu (Navigation bar) becomes collapse unstylish for a few seconds. After a while when the page has fully loaded the menu gets its style.

Comment: pls. try with below css
.header .navi-desktop-site ul li.menu-item-has-children > ul {display: none;}

Comment: @SunnyParsana, Superb job. my problem solving